# Key Error Python while workin' on Dataframe

Tags: python

I always receive a key error when a certain statement is True (INSIDE HE WHILE-LOOP). I just marked it in the Code and gonna show the Error Message below. 
Underneath I also provide some data as example.

```py
def term_check(aenderung,gesamt):
    dict_changes = {}
    list_Update_Term = []
    list_new_term = []
        if pd.isna(df1.iloc[i][3]):
            stopper = True
            k = 0
            while stopper:
                for row in range(len(df2)):
                    if nameObj in df2.iloc[row][6]:   
                        stopper = False
                        break
                    elif k == len(df2):
                        list_new_term.append({"NAME":dict_changes[i]["name"],"TYP":dict_changes[i]["typ"],"IST GÜLTIG": "0"}) """HERE"""
                        stopper = False
                    k += 1
        else:
            namechanged = df1.iloc[i][3]
            stop = True
            k = 0            
            while stop:
                for row in range(len(df2)):
                    if namechanged in df2.iloc[row][6]:
                        print("Error")
                        stop = False
                        break      
                    elif k == len(df2):
                       list_Update_Term.append({"NAME":dict_changes[i]["name"],"TYP":dict_changes[i]["typ"],"IST GÜLTIG": "0"}) """HERE"""
                       stop = False
                    k += 1
    return dict_changes, list_new_term, list_Update_Term
```

ERROR Message:

```
    list_Update_Term.append({"NAME":dict_changes[i]["name"],"TYP":dict_changes[i]["typ"],"IST GÜLTIG": "0"})
KeyError: 5
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] with your code pared down and the data as text, not images

Comment: reduced the code, but don't know how to put my data in a sstructured view.. sorry. Tryin' to figure it out

Comment: I assume this is Python 3, Python 2.7 would be upset by the non-ASCII characters

Comment: where i is defined? you use it in all the function and its not assigned